# Easily Alternate Delimiters in a Join

Tags: python, string, delimiter, implode

I have a list of tuples like so (the strings are fillers... my actual code has unknown values for these):

```
list = [
  ('one', 'two', 'one'),
  ('one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one'),
  ('one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one'...)
]
```

I would like to wrap every other string (in this example, the 'two' strings) in `<strong> </strong>` tags. It's frustrating that I can't do `'<strong>'.join(list)` because every other one won't have the /. This is the only approach I can think of but the use of the flag bothers me... and I can't seem to find anything else on the google machine about this problem.

```
def addStrongs(tuple):
  flag = False
  return_string = ""
  for string in tuple:
    if flag :
      return_string += "<strong>"
    return_string += string
    if flag :
      return_string += "</strong>"
    flag = not flag
  return return_string

formatted_list = map(addStrongs, list)
```

I apologize if this is buggy, I'm still new to python. Is there a better way to do this? I feel like this could be useful in other areas too like adding in left/right quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> tuple = ('one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one')
>>> ['<strong>%s</strong>' % tuple[i] if i%2 else tuple[i] for i in range(len(tuple))]
['one', '<strong>two</strong>', 'one', '<strong>two</strong>', 'one']
```

Comment: about to write the same answer :)

Answer (score 5):

```
from itertools import cycle
xs = ('one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one')
print [t % x for x, t in zip(xs, cycle(['<strong>%s</strong>', '%s']))]
```

Using `cycle` you can apply to more complex patterns than "every other".

Answer (score 2):

[@jhibberd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10271537/989121) is fine, but just in case, here the same idea without imports:

```
a = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i')
formats = ['%s', '<strong>%s</strong>']
print [formats[n % len(formats)] % s for n, s in enumerate(a)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more Pythonic than unbeli's answer:

```
item = ('one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one')
['<strong>%s</strong>' % elem if i % 2 else elem for i, elem in enumerate(item)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` too.  To me it just look cleaner.

```
tuple = ('one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one')
['<strong>%s</strong>' % x if i%2 else x for i, x in enumerate(tuple)]
```